# In PHP, how do I detect which was the *actual* script that caused a fatal error (memory size exceeded)?

Tags: php, debugging, error-handling, fatal-error

I keep getting a mysterious error like this logged:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 134217736 bytes) in C:\BLABLABLA\unrelated.php on line 24
```

Of course, `unrelated.php` is not the script that does the actual function call. It's just one of the many files with wrapper functions in my framework.

My extended PHP error logger, which uses `debug_backtrace()` in order to be able to loop through and log the "full chain" of function calls leading up to the error. However, even that "smart" logger of mine falls short in this case:

```
Allowed memory size of 1,07 GB exhausted (tried to allocate 134,22 MB):

    Row 310 @ "C:\BLABLA\debug.php"
    Row 1844 @ "C:\BLABLA\irrelephpant.php"
```

Neither of those files is the origin script which is actually run, resulting in this error.

All of the files mentioned above are never run directly. They are just part of my framework, wrapping functions from PHP or each other.

I don't understand this. Everything about `debug_backtrace()` seems to suggest that it will find the "outermost"/base script, but it clearly doesn't in this case. I assume it's because a **FATAL** error...? What can I do to make it truly log the actual script that was run in CLI and ended up causing this error? (So that I can assign more RAM for it specifically.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Xdebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdebug) profiler to see where the maximum memory is allocated. You can increase memory size by adding this line in your *unrelated.php* script at top `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');` or whatever memory size increase you need.

Comment: 1. XDebug was always a mystery to me, so I'd rather not have to learn/install/deal with that if possible. 2. Yeah, I know I can add that to other files, but I don't want them to be able to use unlimited/lots of RAM -- only the specific script which really needs it.

Comment: @user17535142 there is no "specific script" there is only your application. The fact that it is comprised of more than one file of source code is irrelevant, especially from a resource management standpoint. Profiling your application is the correct answer.

Comment: @Sammitch Huh? I run `php test.php`. `test.php` makes a function call to `other.php`. `other.php` is the only one that shows up in the error log. How do I get `test.php`? It's really tiresome to have to repeat myself all the time and have people pretend to not understand what I mean.

Comment: Think of the `include('other.php')` statement as simply copy/pasting the contents of `other.php` in place of the include statement in `test.php`. Just because the source code resides inside of a different file does not mean that that file somehow has its own execution context or resource allocations. Breaking PHP code up across multiple helps organize the code so that it's easy for _humans_ to manage and organize. You can include  100 files, but to PHP it's still just one application. Again, if you want to know where the memory is accumulating you need to use a profiler.